# Refactoring methods of a Struct: Cannot borrow `*self` as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable

Tags: rust, refactoring

I would like to create a structure where one field is evolving in function of the others. I can do it, but I think it can be cleverly refactored.

Here is the minimal code for such a goal:

```
struct Example {
    data: Vec<bool>,
    elements: Vec<usize>,
    data2: bool
}

impl Example {
    fn decide(&self, index: usize)-> usize{
        let mut counter = 0;
        for (i,&b) in self.data.iter().enumerate() {
            if b && i < index && self.data2  {
                counter += 1;
            }
        }
        counter
    }

    fn evolve(&mut self){
        for element in self.elements.iter_mut(){
            if self.decide(*element) == 4 {
                *element += 1
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The compiler says that there is an error:
`

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `*self` as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable
  --> src/lib.rs:20:16
   |
19 |         for element in self.elements.iter_mut() {
   |                        ------------------------
   |                        |
   |                        mutable borrow occurs here
   |                        mutable borrow later used here
20 |             if self.decide(*element) == 4 {
   |                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ immutable borrow occurs here
```

In this precise example, it is easy to replace line 13 by `if self.decide(*element) == 4 {` by the whole definition of the decide function and it works:

```
struct Example {
    data: Vec<bool>,
    elements: Vec<usize>,
    data2: bool,
}

impl Example {
    fn evolve(&mut self) {
        for element in self.elements.iter_mut() {
            let mut counter = 0;
            for (i, &b) in self.data.iter().enumerate() {
                if b && i < *element && self.data2 {
                    counter += 1;
                }
            }
            if counter == 4 {
                *element += 1
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But in my case, the decide function is big and I want to reduce the size of evolve. Is it possible to do so?

Comment: Please post the full error message from `cargo check`, not your IDE (rust-analyzer now has a way to show it).

Comment: Split `elements` and `data2` to a different struct.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman That would be something like this [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=45a65ae579ae72f333849390765c6ae5).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest fix is to pass `decide()` the data it needs instead of it taking `&self`:

```
fn decide(data: &[bool], data2: bool, index: usize) -> usize {
    let mut counter = 0;
    for (i, &b) in data.iter().enumerate() {
        if b && i < index && data2 {
            counter += 1;
        }
    }
    counter
}

fn evolve(&mut self) {
    for element in self.elements.iter_mut() {
        if Self::decide(&self.data, self.data2, *element) == 4 {
            *element += 1
        }
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=08e3e90a87aba0890aea072407474fca)